# Discord Bot Escribir mensaje a una hora especifica

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Básicamente llevo 2 semanas rompiéndome la cabeza de como podría hacer que mi Bot de Discord envié un mensaje a una hora especifica...

He probado con **CRON** y de momento no se como usarlo bien para sacarle provecho.

```
function maintenance1(){
  switch (day) {
    case 1:
      msg.channel.send("Luni este maintenance la ora 3:30 am.")
      break;
    case 2:
      msg.channel.send("Marti nu este maintenance.")
      break;
    case 3:
      msg.channel.send("Miercuri este maintenance la ora 3:30 am.")
      break;
    case 4:
      msg.channel.send("Joi nu este maintenance.")
      break;
    case 5:
      msg.channel.send("Vineri este maintenance la ora 2:00 am.")
      break;
    case 6:
      msg.channel.send("Sambata este maintenance la ora 2:00 am.")
      break;
    case 7:
      msg.channel.send("Duminica nu este maintenance.")
      break;
    default:
  }

}
```

Esto es una  función en la que me devuelve el dia de hoy.

```
function getToday() {
    let today = new Date();
    let months = [`January`, `February`, `March`, `April`, `May`, `June`, `July`, `August`, `September`, `October`, `November`, `December`];
    let suffix = [`st`, `nd`, `rd`];
    return `${today.getDate()}${suffix[today.getDate()] || `th`} of ${months[today.getMonth()]}`;
}
```

Esto es otra función en la que me devuelve la hora y fecha de hoy.
Pero no se como usar esto para compararlo con una hora especifica.

```
  function mueveReloj(){
      momentoActual = new Date()
      hora = momentoActual.getHours()
      minuto = momentoActual.getMinutes()
      segundo = momentoActual.getSeconds()

      str_segundo = new String (segundo)
      if (str_segundo.length == 1)
         segundo = "0" + segundo

      str_minuto = new String (minuto)
      if (str_minuto.length == 1)
         minuto = "0" + minuto

      str_hora = new String (hora)
      if (str_hora.length == 1)
         hora = "0" + hora

      horaImprimible = hora + " : " + minuto + " : " + segundo

      document.form_reloj.reloj.value = horaImprimible

      setTimeout("mueveReloj()",1000)
  }
```

A mi me interesaria algo asi.. pero al ponerlo mi bot se crashea..

Estaba intentando sacar la hora local del equipo o servidor donde esta hosteado mi bot y compararla con una hora especifica ej = 12:00

Si la hora local coincide con las 12:00 
quiero un mensaje en el canal.

```
   function hora(){
        var hora = get.hour();
        return hora;
   }

   function dia(){
        var dia= get.day();
        return dia;
   }

   if (hora() === '12:00' && dia() === 'lunes') {
       message.channel.send(' Dentro de una hora hay mantenimiento')}
```

Algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuando dices que has probado con CRON ¿te refieres al demonio de tu servidor o a una librería como [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron)?

Comment: Libreria node-cron

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el código que has usado? No hay relación entre el uso de la librería y ese `switch`

Comment: el código en el que usaba cron lo he borrado porque no tenia ni idea de como usarlo adecuadamente.

Answer (score 0):

La documentación de [node-cron](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron) es bastante clara con su ejemplo:

```
const CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
const cronExpr = '0 0 2 * * *';
let job = new CronJob(cronExpr, function() {
  console.log('Mensaje mandado cada día a las 2am');
}, 'Europe/Madrid');
job.start();
```

Comment: pues no lo entiendo =((( ahora debo utilizar "job.start()" y compararlo con dia.get.hour() ? o como ???

Comment: ¿Sabes cómo funcionan las expresiones cron?https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/2010/02/22/expresiones-cron/

Comment: actualmente no, tendria que leerme bien la documentacion y entenderla, cosa que no entendi leyendo la primera documentacion https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron

Answer (score 0):

```
cron.schedule("1 1 21 * * 4", function() {
    console.log("maintenance");
    client.channels.find(c => c.name === 'announcement')
        .send('Mentenanta la ora 3:30.');
});
```

Comment: Hola Andrei Drew, las publicaciones que son sólo código se consideran de baja calidad y no suelen ser de ayuda a otros usuarios. Por favor, añade algo más de información: ¿qué hace el código? ¿cómo soluciona el problema? ¿dónde iría en el código de la pregunta? Lee [answer] para más información.

Comment: Y también: ¿es esto una respuesta o un intento de edición? Si es información nueva, deberías editar la pregunta en lugar de añadir una respuesta... y si es una respuesta, entonces deberías añadir más detalle como comentaba arriba.